# Automatic log-out if no activity found on page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to make a script, which can automatically check whether the user is performing some activity on screen page.
If no activity is received in 1 minute, then I want to alert him with asking reason of being idle.
I think this can be done in jquery/javascript and php.
Can someone please give me anything so that I can make my dream possible.

And if he don't clicks on any of the item, then automatic log-out after total 1 minutes.

Comment: what is it that you have tried ?

Comment: i donot have any idea how to implement this. Thats why i asked here.

Comment: Try setTimeout() in js, but put some effort into figuring it out on your own first. If you don't put any effort into it, why should we?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[idle plugin](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/a-new-and-improved-jquery-idle-timeout-plugin/)

This plugin do the trick

```
<!-- dialog window markup -->
<div id="dialog" title="Your session is about to expire!">
   <p>You will be logged off in <span id="dialog-countdown"></span> seconds.</p>
   <p>Do you want to continue your session?</p>
</div>



// setup the dialog
$("#dialog").dialog({
 autoOpen: false,
 modal: true,
 width: 400,
 height: 200,
 closeOnEscape: false,
 draggable: false,
 resizable: false,
 buttons: {
    'Yes, Keep Working': function(){
        // Just close the dialog. We pass a reference to this
        // button during the init of the script, so it'll automatically
        // resume once clicked
        $(this).dialog('close');
    },
    'No, Logoff': function(){
        // fire whatever the configured onTimeout callback is.
        $.idleTimeout.options.onTimeout.call(this);
    }
 }
});

// start the plugin
$.idleTimeout('#dialog', 'div.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:first', {
idleAfter: 300, // user is considered idle after 5 minutes of no movement
pollingInterval: 60, // a request to keepalive.php (below) will be sent to the server every minute
keepAliveURL: 'keepalive.php',
serverResponseEquals: 'OK', // the response from keepalive.php must equal the text "OK"
onTimeout: function(){

    // redirect the user when they timeout.
    window.location = "timeout.htm";

},
onIdle: function(){

    // show the dialog when the user idles
    $(this).dialog("open");

},
onCountdown: function(counter){

    // update the counter span inside the dialog during each second of the countdown
    $("#dialog-countdown").html(counter);

},
onResume: function(){

    // the dialog is closed by a button in the dialog
    // no need to do anything else

}
});
```

and using **ajax** you can send the request to server to close the **session**

Comment: Thanks brother. It is really great. But I want to add a drop down on it, which will appear when user is idle. And in the alert time he can select any value as reason of being idle.

Comment: yes. then add your html in the **div** with id **dialog** like 
`<select id='idleReason'><option value='Away'>Away</option>....</select>` and using the id of **select** you can take the value of it and send it to browser like `$('#idleReason').val()`
I think it will help you

Comment: ankur, i am new to javascript, AJX and jquery also. Here is the code i have written can you please modify that so that I can send the data from **options** to AJAX. 
http://pastebin.com/SiQtN7Rq

I would be grateful to you.

Comment: Hi, I must say that this plugin is superb.
Can you please help me in one thing, I want to Resume the timer. I wrote this, as I also want to get the data from server. But onresume is not working.
Can you please help in this?


$.get("test1.php?data="+message, function(result){
//      $("div").html(result);
$('#idletimeout').html(result)._onResume();
    });

Comment: http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-idle-timeout/example-dialog.htm
See this is the live example...you can take help from there

Answer (score 3):

- set a variable to indicate user activity, initially false
- set a variable indicating the current time
- set a document wide click handler to set user activity to true when a user clicks anywhere in the page
- set a listener function, using `setTimeout`, to check the time past and the first variable. If it's true, cancel listening, otherwise if the time past is < a minute continue listening, if time past > 1 minute alert the user and take your action

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/BXmmA/) for a q&d example of this algorithm

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You have to add different event handlers on body tag to determine if user is inactive. I think onmousemove, oncllick and onkeypress events will be enough.

- you should start a timer and when it hits a specific time you just go to the log out URL
- implement mentioned event handlers. Inside them reset the timer.

This will do.